# Turning data from firebase realtime database into an array in react-native

Tags: firebase, react-native

I created a component in react that reads data from the real-time databaase from firebase, pushes it to two arrays and then plots this on a line chart. It works, however does not update automatically when new data is added to the database, it only does so when I refresh.

This is the code I currently have

[current code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B6Jke.png)

Comment: Do check out [code formatting](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) on SO -- makes the question more searchable :)

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is that you should be using `state` to store your `timeArray` and `humidityArray`

My theory is that your values *are* being updated correctly, the issue is just that React Native doesn't know that they were updated, and so won't re-render.

Read more about the `useState` hook [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html)

Comment: so then I have: const [timeArray, setTimeArray] = useState([]); and const [humidityArray, setHumdidityArray] = useState([]); how do I use setTimeArray and setHumidityArray though?

Comment: Right! So you can just call `set...Array` in your `onValue` function with the complete array.

Comment: I tried this: setTimeArray(...timeArray, \`${property}\`); but this does not work